# moments does not correctly parse a string

Tags: node.js, string, date, parsing, momentjs

I have that date:

02.05.2020 12:33:08

What means:

**day** 02

**month** 05

**year** 2020

**hour** 12

**minute** 33

**second** 08

I want to parse it to a date object via following call, but the returned day is wrong:

```
    moment("02.05.2020 12:33:08").day() => returned 3 ???
```

Why is it wrong parsed by momentjs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you'll need to supply a format to allow moment to parse the date correctly.

See the docs here: [Moment parse string+format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

Once you do this, you should get the correct result:

```js
const dateFormat = "DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss";
const parsedDate = moment("02.05.2020 12:33:08", dateFormat);
console.log("Day of week:", parsedDate.day());
console.log("Day of month:", parsedDate.date());
console.log("Full date:", parsedDate.format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, HH:mm:ss"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: but the returned day is now 6, should it not be 2 because its the second may?

Comment: hey, @Prutheus, the day() function gives the day of the week. If you want the day of the month use date(), see https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are two potential problems.

First, if you run just the parsing on its own (like at the command-line [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop), you get the following warning.

> Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release.

So, that might not be the best string to parse, depending on your version.

But also, [`.day()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/) gives you a day of the week index.  February 5th was a Wednesday, and since Moment is counting days from Sunday, that's almost certainly the right answer.  If you want the day of the *month* (5), that's `.date()`, instead.

Actually, there's a *third* potential problem, in that "02" and "05" make for an ambiguous date, so you probably want to feed Moment a parse string, a second parameter that looks something like `"MM.DD.YYYY hh:mm:ss"`.